# lenovo y520 ram and ssd upgrade

Tags: memory, ssd

I am using Lenovo y520. now everything is fine. but I want to increase the ram and ssd to 1TB. I am not sure about the spec of this laptop eg. the extra slots for SSD and the exact spec for the ram.

is it possible to increase them without removing the existing one ?
PS: I tried to reach support within the period of warranty but they did not respond well.now it is not within the warranty period. it comes with one SSD and RAM so i just want to add more budget doesn't matter. but hardware must support the system environment.

```
    Device name some device name
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.86 GB usable)
Device ID   some device id
Product ID  some product id
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
```

[image: storage controller]

[image: storage disk drive]
thx
sayantan

Comment: What is your budget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop supports up to 32gb of ram in the two slots it has.
To see whether you can add or have to replace. Check task manager. Under memory there is a used slots indication.

it seems to have one 2.5inch sata slot and one pci-e m.2 slot availible in total.
that seems to be all the space you have.

Comment: so I won't be able to add ssd hdd into this laptop? but I may update ram. am I right? 
can you share the exact ram that I can add to this?

Comment: If you don't already have two drives you could upgrade I edited the post to better name the bay. since it's just a 2.5inch sata bay. I see no reason why an ssd wouldn't work. I can't point you to an exact ram kit, the site only mentions Up to 32 GB DDR4; 2 x SODIMM Slots. but doesn't seem to have a compatibility or maximum speed chart.

Comment: possibly it has a disk drive attached to this. it came with 1 ssd nvme i guess 250gb.